# Tzedakah and Maaser - one obligation or two?

Tags: halacha, money, tzedakah-charity, maaser-tithes, nedarim-shevuot

I understand that the obligation to give Maaser from our income is a sub-category of the overall commandment to give Tzedakah but consider the following question:

If I made a promise (Neder) to give Tzedakah every day. Can I take Maaser money that I have set aside and use that to fulfill my vow ? or do I have to give the Maaser money in the name (LeShem) Maaser and money from my post Maaser earnings to (LeShem) Tzedakah?

Comment: Probably depends on 1. your intention when you made the daily-vow and 2. your intention when you started to give Maaser, as dicussed in Maaser Kesafim by Domb et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give Tzedakah with Maaser money, as long you don't have an **obligation** to give that Tzedakah. Example: Someone got an Aliya. The cost of the Aliya was $180. He is not permited to deduct it from Maaser, but he can be Menadev (pledge) $180 from his Maaser when he has an aliya.

You can read [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_47397_34.pdf) and [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pagefeed/hebrewbooks_org_47299_427.pdf) for more info.

Comment: IIRC, if your intention was to use Maaser money for buying the Aliya, it may be deducted from Maaser, according to Domb et al's book. Maaser Kesafim - http://www.amazon.com/Maaser-Kesafim-Giving-Tenth-Charity/dp/087306304X